# How to get count of all element in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

suppose I have an array in numpy

```
array([1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7])
```

What I want is to get two arrays to give count of each element:

```
array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
array([1,1,1,1,3,1,4])
```

How can I do this without any for loops?

Comment: does list comprehension count as for loop?

Comment: I would like to use numpy function.

Comment: Note, in your example the second array should start with a 2 since there are 2 '1's in your input.  That is, unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: You have two of 1s not one.

Comment: You can use `Counter` from `collections` library. Then you can create two of desired `np` arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [1043]: np.unique(np.array([1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7]),return_counts=True)
Out[1043]: (array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7])
>>> b = np.bincount(a)
>>> b[np.unique(a)]
array([2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4])
```

And to get the other array :

```
>>> np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems bincount cost a lot of memory.

Comment: @maple it is however faster to compute than `np.unique` (you can check using `timeit`)